# storing 64 bit address in some variable of 32bit application

Tags: x86, 32bit-64bit, 32-bit, type-conversion

i have 32 bit application which communicates with 64bit appication. The 64 bit application returns the address to 32 bit application. Since 64bit address requires 8 bytes of data. What should be data type used in 32bit application?
i tried using UINT64 but sizeof operator retured 4 bytes.
How can i solve this problem

Comment: Which programming language are you using?

Comment: Just don't exchange pointer values between processes.  Use the rand() function instead.  The value it generates is just as relevant to the receiving process and has a predictable size.

Comment: im using c++
and i have to exchange pointers.. this is pre-written code where one application has been converted to 64bit. So i have to somehow place the value of address in 32bit application for further processing

Comment: And also if in my address of 64bit only lower 32 bits are significant.. i can truncate the handle. how do i do that?